# How to merge two tables before doing a inner join?

Tags: mysql

```
TABLE user
    - id
    - username
    - email
    - passwd

TABLE user_external 
    - id
    - username
    - email
    - passwd

TABLE orders
    - id
    - user_id
    - product
```

I have two tables containg userinformation i want to merge in order to get usersname on a order. 
my select only fetches the name from the user table (and leaves the ones from external blank), but not the user_external.

Is there a way to UNION users tables, and then do a left join?

```
select 
orders.product,
merged_user_table.name as name
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN merged_user_table user_assigned_to ON o.user_id = merged_user_table.id
WHERE
orders.id = 1
```

Comment: Yes you can use `union` and then do the join and finally perhaps an order by clause.

Comment: examples on this is appricciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
SELECT
    orders.product
    ,merged_user_table.name as name
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id,username,email,passwd
    FROM user
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,username,email,passwd
    FROM user_external
) merged_user_table user_assigned_to
    ON o.user_id = merged_user_table.id
WHERE
    orders.id = 1
```

I have assumed that the `user` and `user_external` tables' users are distinct. Using `UNION` without `ALL` will effectively perform a `SELECT DISTINCT` between the two selects in the subquery, which would be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a sub query the get a unioned table, then join that to orders, this does mean the main join won't use an index.

As such I would probably use 2 separate queries, one joining orders with user and the other joining orders with user_external, and union the results together.

This should work (using an INNER JOIN rather than a LEFT OUTER JOIN - can't see why you are using a LEFT OUTER JOIN but there might be a reason). You have specified to bring back a column called name, but neither user table has such a column so not sure if you mean to bring back the user name or the table name - so the below example SQL brings back both.

```
SELECT orders.product,
        user.username as name,
        'user' as table_name
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN user 
ON o.user_id = user.id
WHERE orders.id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT orders.product,
        user_external.username as name,
        'user_external' as table_name
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN user_external  
ON o.user_id = user_external.id
WHERE orders.id = 1
```